# tabs inside a user control not working

Tags: vb.net, user-controls

i'm trying to create a user control with tabs and inside of each tab i'm displaying user control.

i'm already using it in my existing project but i used it in page and it is working and now i'm trying to do it in user control but it wont work. it looks like a problem in user-control or my code.

can anyone help me with my problem? thanks in advance

see my code below for details.

```
 <%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="ucMemberInfo.ascx.vb"
    Inherits="CallCenterWebApp.ucMemberInfo" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/UserControls/MemberProfile.ascx" TagName="MemberInformation"
    TagPrefix="uc1" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/UserControls/ContractDetailsCC.ascx" TagName="ContractDetailsCC"
    TagPrefix="uc2" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/UserControls/CorporateInfo.ascx" TagName="CorporateInfo" TagPrefix="uc3" %>

<!-- MESSAGE -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="eight columns centered">
        <asp:Literal ID="litMessage" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- MESSAGE -->
<!-- DATA TABS -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 medium-12 columns">
        <div class="row collapse">
            <dl class="tabs" data-tab>
                <dd class="active large-4 medium-4 text-center">
                    <a href="#panel1">Member Information</a></dd>
                <dd class="large-4 medium-4 text-center">
                    <a href="#panel2">Corporate Benefits</a></dd>
                <dd class="large-4 medium-4 text-center">
                    <a href="#panel3">Corporate Information</a></dd>
            </dl>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- DATA TABS -->

<div class="tabs-content">
    <!-- START PANEL1 -->
    <div class="content active large-12 medium-12 columns" id="panel1">            
        <uc1:MemberInformation id="ucMemberProfile" runat="server" />          
    </div>
    <!-- END PANEL1 -->
    <!-- START PANEL2 -->
    <div class="content large-12 columns" id="panel2">
        <uc2:ContractDetailsCC ID="ucContractDetailsCC" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <!--- END PANEL2 -->
    <!-- START PANEL3 -->
    <div class="content large-12 columns" id="panel3">
        <!-- CORPORATE INFORMATION -->
        <uc7:CorporateInfo ID="ucCorporateInfo" runat="server" />          
        <!-- CORPORATE INFORMATION -->
    </div>
    <!--- END PANEL3 -->
</div>
```

Comment: Can you describe what isn't working?

Comment: @AndrewMortimer i cant click tab :(